# Как реализовать анимацию блока при прокрутке страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, прокрутка

Добрый день! Помогите, пожалуйста, с анимацией.
У себя на странице использую плагин https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr, но использовать целый плагин только для нескольких эффектов, считаю, не разумным. А именно мне нужен только один эффект - движение при прокрутке страницы только трех блоков (изменение у них `margin`).
Пример с плагином skrollr https://jsfiddle.net/LADYX/q7dw096f/
Смысл в следующем:
У картинки в стиле по умолчанию указано свойство `margin-left: 10px;`
Скрипт же должен присваивать этой картинке свойство `margin-left: 50px;`
Когда начинаем прокручивать страницу, докручиваем до картинки, и когда она только появляется внизу экрана, у нее свойство `margin-left: 50px;`
Прокручиваем ее дальше, и картинка доходя до цента экрана (имеется ввиду по вертикали) плавно уменьшает свойство до `margin-left: 10px;`
И тоже самое обратно, от цетра экрана к низу экрана картинка свойство меняет с margin-left: 10px; на margin-left: 50px;
Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Надо смотреть в направлении `$(window).scrollTop()`: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q7dw096f/1/)

Наверное стоит добавить `data-*` аттрибутов по которым вы будете делать проверку.

Comment: Так это совсем просто тогда, вам нужно посчитать процент прокрутки и на его основе двигать картинку (тут уже много вариантов в зависимости от того, как это должно в финале выглядеть); если как в примере то не `margin` а `position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 10px;`

Comment: Так скриптом он встанет поверх вашего стиля (напрямую в dom важнее чем css); `$('.mydiv').css({margin:'50px'});`